# Javascript/AJAX request not/not proper working in IE/chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am writing a simple PHP/JS script to determine and manage status of all windows terminal servers. 
As you know the access via WMI is very slow so I want AJAX to show the progress of each server when he is looping every server. 
The code works as expected in firefox. 
In chrome the code works, but does not show a status while looping. After the loop the content is displayed.
In IE11 the code does not work. Checking by alerts IE calls both functions and also gets in if statement creating requestobject. 
Can somebody help me to get IE working and Chrome showing status? 
Thank you for your help.

My code looks like this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tsmanager.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
 function refreshall()
 {
  var table = document.getElementById("terminalservers");
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
  {
   var sComputer = row.id;
   if (sComputer != "")
   {
    setTimeout(refresh(sComputer), 2000); 
    setTimeout(document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = sComputer, 2000); 
   }

  }

 }
 
 function refresh(sComputer)
 {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else 
  {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
  req.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
   if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
   {
    document.getElementById(sComputer).innerHTML = req.responseText;
   }
  }
  req.open("GET", "serverrequest.php?name="+sComputer, false);
  req.send();
 }
 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="terminalservers">

  /* some table content with row id=servername */


</table> 
<button onclick="refreshall()">alle</button>
<br><span id="turn">leer</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at using jQuery - it provides simple and robust cross-browser support for AJAX and results in much more readable code on all fronts.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. But I dont want to use jquery. I wanna keep it simple. I know the advantages of jquery but I want to avoid a external lib.